# How to use web service search/get methods

Tags: sql, web-services

i would like to be able to retrieve results from this search by connecting directly to their database instead of screen-scraping:

http://broinc.com/search.php

would it be possible to return the results programmatically into some variable, instead of manually doing this search and then going through every page to get the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If server provides such direct access, probably you may. For example, via SQL TCP/IP port.

But much more often used and best-practice way - via web service search/get methods.

Comment: thank you. how do i get started with the web service search/get methods?

Comment: @jenny - answer depends greatly on your programming language, is this an asp.net website, rails, php, java?

Comment: @RPM1984: i dont know what they are running but here's the website: http://broinc.com/search.php

Comment: @jenny Screen-scraping that site may well be in violation of laws on immaterial rights, such as copyright laws. There is no method besides screen-scraping to get data from sites that do not actively support it. They seem to have a friendly tech support though; why not contact them? :)